# MS Access correctly utilizing a string variable within DLookup

Tags: variables, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to replace the domain parameter of DLookup with a variable, the intent being a single place to make a change if one is required.  This is how I am declaring the variable:

```
Dim MnMnuSettingTbl As String
MnMnuSettingTbl = "'tblMainMenu'"
```

This is the original segment where the variable is to be used:

```
Me.MainMenuChoiceOne.Caption = DLookup("BtnText", "tblMainMenu", "ID = 1")
```

I wish to replace the domain criteria "tblMainMenu" with the variable, but when I attempt to do so it either does not compile, or I get an error message stating the table can not be found.  I have reviewed several articles on this matter, and I am gathering I am not passing the variable correctly, via the improper use of single or double quotes.  I'm rather embarrassed, so at this point I am looking for the correct way to either format the variable or the correct way to use it within the DLookup context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable must contain the same constant string as you currently have in the DLookup.

```vb
MnMnuSettingTbl = "tblMainMenu"
Me.MainMenuChoiceOne.Caption = DLookup("BtnText", MnMnuSettingTbl , "ID = 1")
```

Single quotes would be needed for string parameters in the WHERE clause, e.g.

```vb
strTextID = "'QD42'"
x = DLookup("foo", "bar", "TextID = " & strTextID)
```